# VBA Code: How to parse out each First, Middle, and Last names from an input function and then using that to count the characters

Tags: excel, vba

- I am very confused on where I am at right now. But I need to parse/separate out the first, middle, and last name of a input function. Then display the number of characters that is in that entire name minus the spaces as well as display the number of characters in users first and last names minus the spaces.

ex: Matt Lose Wright has 15 Characters
Matt Wright has 10 Characters

I am trying

My Code:

```
Sub ParseName()
    Dim name As String
    name = InputBox("Enter First Name, Middle Name, and Last Name")
    
    Dim First As Double
    Dim Middle As Double
    Dim Last As Double
    
    First = InStr(1, name, "First", vbTextCompare)
    Middle = InStr(2, name, "Middle", vbTextCompare)
    Last = InStr(3, name, "Last", vbTextCompare)
    
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim n As Integer
    Count = 0
    name = InputBox("Enter First Name, Middle Name, and Last Name")
    If name = "" Then
        For Each Cell In Selection
         n = InStr(1, Cell.Value, name)
         While n <> 0
            Count = Count + 1
            n = InStr(n + 1, Cell.Value, name)
         Wend
      Next Cell
    MsgBox Count & " Occurrences of " & name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: instr searches a string for another substring.  it does not set a variable.  nor does the first criterion mean which item in the string but it means the starting point in the larger string you want to search for the substring.  So you are basically searching for the literal `First` in the string provided.

Comment: Okay that kind of makes sense I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To summarise** - I have shown you **three techniques**.

```
A = "Matt Lose Wright"
B = Split(A, " ")
MsgBox Len(Replace(A, " ", ""))
For Each name in B
    MsgBox Name & " " & Len(Name)
Next
MsgBox B(0) & " " & B(UBound(B)) & " " & Len(B(0)) & " " & Len(B(UBound(B)))
```

**Output**

```
14
Matt 4
Lose 4
Wright 6
Matt Wright 4 6
```

See `Split`, your friend when parsing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

```
A = "Matt Lose Win Wright"
B = Split(A, " ")
MsgBox Len(Replace(A, " ", ""))
For Each name in B
    MsgBox Name & " " & Len(Name)
Next
MsgBox B(0) & " " & B(UBound(B)) & " " & Len(B(0)) & " " & Len(B(UBound(B)))
```

**Output**

```
17
Matt 4
Lose 4
Win 3
Wright 6
Matt Wright 4 6
```

Comment: Yeah but I have to find a way to count a split ?

Comment: Did you run the code. That's what `ubound` does. The code handles multiple middle names as well.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water but cannot force it to drink. Perhaps you should give up.

Comment: You are just after code you can copy and paste and don't want to learn anything.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water but is that horse going to drink that dirty water