# How to separate a string and counting the number of characters in a string minus the spaces

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need help with my code that displays an input box and the user inputs a name then the code splits the names and counts the names displaying the following:

```
Sub ParseName()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim n As Integer
    
    Count = 0
    Name = InputBox("Enter First Name, Middle Name, and Last Name")
    If Name = "" Then
        For Each Cell In Selection
         n = InStr(1, Cell.Value, Name)
         While n <> 0
            Count = Count + 1
            n = InStr(n + 1, Cell.Value, Name)
      Next Cell
    MsgBox Count & " Occurrences of " & Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: where at in the line of code?

Comment: I am trying to get a code that uses an input box that ask the user to type in a full name. Example: Jeff Allen Joines. From there I need to split the name in a first, middle, and last. From there it needs to count the characters minus the spaces and display a MsgBox like the above image. That counts the number of characters of the full name and counts the characters of the first and last name.

Comment: I hope that makes sense

Comment: No, this is strictly VBA pure coding no excel cell manipulation.

Comment: I hope that helps because I am a little lost right now

Comment: Any luck @milo5m

Comment: He has already asked this and received an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980244/vba-code-how-to-parse-out-each-first-middle-and-last-names-from-an-input-func/73980533#73980533 and gee it has the same code as the accepted answer. `MsgBox Len(Replace(A, " ", ""))` - **but his question asked for more than that**. He asked per word and first and last names only.

Comment: *VBA Code: How to parse out each First, Middle, and Last names from an input function and then using that to count the characters* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980244/vba-code-how-to-parse-out-each-first-middle-and-last-names-from-an-input-func/73980533#73980533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Code: How to parse out each First, Middle, and Last names from an input function and then using that to count the characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980244/vba-code-how-to-parse-out-each-first-middle-and-last-names-from-an-input-func)

Comment: No @ChrisStrickland I am trying to learn man not steal code

Comment: He answered that specifically to address your question, so it's not stealing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.  You could split the names, but it probably wouldn't help.  VBA's split doesn't allow you to split on single characters, AFAIK, as other languages might if you split them a specific delimiter.  So you could just loop through the characters using MID to see if each letter is a space or not.

There is a way without any splitting or looping.  You can just replace the space and get the length of the what's left.

```
Len(Replace(Name, " ", ""))
```

where REPLACE just replaces one string with another, in this case replacing all the spaces with nothing, and LEN just counts the characters in a string.

Here's your code rewritten to use this method, with the unnecessary code and variables removed.  I would also change the Name variable, since I believe that is a reserved word in VBA.  It will let you do it, but you're potentially impacting some existing behavior.  For this particular purpose, using a standalone function to get the character count is someh

```
Sub ParseName()

    Dim fullName As String, charCount As Integer
    
    fullName = InputBox("Enter First Name, Middle Name, and Last Name")
    If fullName <> "" Then
        charCount = Len(Replace(fullName, " ", ""))
        MsgBox fullName & " has " & charCount & " characters"
        End If
    
End Sub
```

Bear in mind, however, that there are plenty of other character codes you might not want to count.  Tabs, new lines, any of a number of whitespace characters.  Non-character symbols.  Things of that nature.

Also, this code does not check that the string even contains letters, or that the user input has three names, or that it is in the format First Middle Last.

Comment: I apologize Chris those type of functions is over my head. But thank you for the help. I am at the point of only using Subs and using for loops.

Comment: A function is exactly like a sub except that it returns a value.  The only control structure I have used is a FOR loop.  I have edited the answer.  Take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris the code works perfect, but the code is a little more advanced than I can do lol but thank you for the help

Comment: Go back and look at it again, I actually was editing it this whole time.  I just didn't expect you to be reading it so soon.  The code at the top should be pretty simple.

Comment: For that If statement what is actually happening. Also is there a way to run the code without a function option? I haven't got to that part of VBA

Comment: I reedited it.  I took out all the other stuff, although depending on the rest of your requirements, you're going to need to do something more complex than what this is doing.  See if the explanation makes sense.

Comment: Thank you again Chris I see where I messed up at. I wrote a Venn diagram of my thinking process and wrote one for yours and definitely makes more sense now.

Comment: @MattFlower `Len(Replace(Name, " ", ""))` same as my answer. Plus my answer addresses your additional requirements. Plus I gave you three techniques. The now deleted answer, when the author realised you had re asked the same question that I had already answered, also contained the same code as in my answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980244/vba-code-how-to-parse-out-each-first-middle-and-last-names-from-an-input-func/73980533#73980533. **This question should be closed.**

Comment: This is its requirements - *VBA Code: How to parse out each First, Middle, and Last names from an input function and then using that to count the characters*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980244/vba-code-how-to-parse-out-each-first-middle-and-last-names-from-an-input-func/73980533#73980533

Comment: Why don't you just post an answer the question and let @MattFlower accept it?  But I am fine with voting to close it, given that it has already been answered.

Comment: I apologize that I am not a good coder

Comment: I am just trying to learn the whole process @ChrisStrickland